# Where would this maven dependency be coming from?

Tags: android, maven, gson, pom.xml

I am getting this warning and then error when it tries to download this mysterious + version of gson.  My POM is requesting version 2.3.1 but not this mysterious +.  So where would this be coming from? I also have a similar issue with Android Support v20  My POM is requesting v18 but its trying to pull V20.

```
[WARNING] The POM for com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:+ is missing, no dependency information available

org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: The following artifacts could not be resolved: com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:+, com.android.support:support-v4:jar:20.+: Failure to find com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:+ in file://C:\Dev\git\MyApp\main/../repo was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of repo has elapsed or updates are forced
```

I have tried the force update by doing mvn install -U  but that didn't help either.

In my POM.xml

```
 <dependency>
       <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
       <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
       <version>2.3.1</version>
   </dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

do

```
mvn clean
```

and then

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

and analyze what is pulling this dependency

Comment: Thanks.   I tried that but it doesn't seem to show the dependencies pulled in by the dependencies.  I figured out by inspecting the POMs of dependencies that one of the ones I was using was requesting just a "+" version of GSON.  After removing that this was resolved.